# UITextView strange issue in setting frame

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview, uitextview

[image]

The above is what I get on the simulator regardless of the frame I set for the UITextView. The above UITextView is a subview to UIScrollView (the light gray view behind). And this UIScrollView has been presented modally. No matter what frame I set for the UITextView, its height remains as shown above. What could be the problem?

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 540, 620)];
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 520, 80)];
textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
textView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
[scrollView addSubview:textView];
```

Thanks!

Noted one more thing. Changing the width of the textview from say the above 520 to 220 does indeed result in a change of width and it shows. But no matter what the value of height is, the textview keeps displaying with the same height as in the above image.

Comment: Can you show us code where you are creating UITextView programmatically and adding to UIScrollView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your UITextView size is dependent on the Height and width of UIScrollView first increase the size of UIScrollView size than increase th eUITextView size.

Comment: The scrollview is properly framed and contentSize has also been set properly. As far as I can see, no issues on that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same issue and when I try to po the frame height it give me:

```
property 'frame' not found on object of type 'UITextView *'
```

This is after installing the new ios6 dev kit... so maybe that's it...

Yup that's it. If you go to file inspector in your xib or storyboard and untick "use autolayout" then that will help.. But's it's screwed everything, so I'm just going to make the damned uitextview programatically!